# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}\geq1+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{2(ab+ac+bc)}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution, uvw

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $ab+ac+bc\neq0$. Prove that:
$$\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\geq1+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{2(ab+ac+bc)}$$
I tried C-S, uvw, BW and more, but without success.

Comment: Does the following hold? $\frac{z}{z+y}+\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{y}{y+x}\geq\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @yurnero No, it does not hold. $\inf\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}=1$

Comment: @yurnero Try $c=0$ and $a\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: Thanks. I also just checked $$\frac{z}{z+y}+\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{y}{y+x}-\frac{3}{2}=\frac{(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}{2(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}$$ which is neither always nonpositive nor always nonnegative. Well interesting problem. +1 and good luck.

Comment: I proved this inequality!!! Thanks to all!

Comment: If you proved it, you should post an answer, instead of leaving us in the dark after torturing our minds :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Michael Rosenberger Thanks, here is my $0.02:

Write the whole inequality in terms of $ab, ac, bc$:

$$\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}=\frac{ac}{ac+bc}+\frac{ab}{ab+ac}+\frac{bc}{bc+ab}$$

Then use the following inequality proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017110/inequality-with-five-variables) - as a Lemma inside Andreas's answer:

$$  \frac{a}{a+b} + \frac{b}{b+c} + \frac{c}{c+a} \geq  1+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{a \, b \ c}}{2(a+b+c)}$$

for $a\leftarrow ac$, $b\leftarrow ab$, $c\leftarrow bc$

That's all.

Comment: Wow! It's beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

This proof I found a few minutes ago.

I hope that there is something nicer.

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, $abc=w^3$ and $v^2=xw^2$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq\frac{w^2}{2v^2}-\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)(a+c)(b+c)\geq\left(\frac{w^2}{v^2}-1\right)\prod_{cyc}(a+b)$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)c^2\geq\left(\frac{w^2}{v^2}-1\right)(9uv^2-w^3)$$ or
$$(9uv^2-w^3)(v^2-w^2)\geq v^2(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$
and since $v^2\geq w^2$, it remains to prove that
$$(9uv^2-w^3)^2(v^2-w^2)^2\geq v^4(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$$ or
$$(9uv^2-w^3)^2(v^2-w^2)^2\geq 27v^4(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ 
or $f(u)\geq0$, where
$$f(u)=108v^4w^3u^3-81v^4w^2(2v^2-w^2)u^2-18v^2w^3(10v^4-2v^2w^2+w^4)u+$$
$$+108v^{10}+28v^4w^6-2v^2w^8+w^{10},$$
which says that for $u_{min}$ we get the following equation:
$$324u^2v^4w^3-162v^4w^2(2v^2-w^2)u-18v^2w^3(10v^4-2v^2w^2+w^4)=0,$$
which gives 
$$u_{min}=\frac{6v^3-3vw^2+\sqrt{36v^6+44v^4w^2-7v^2w^4+8w^6}}{12vw}$$.

Thus, it remains to prove that $f\left(u_{min}\right)\geq0$, which gives
$$648x^5-396x^4+342x^3+107x^2+20x+8\geq\sqrt{x(36x^3+44x^2-7x+8)^3}$$ or
$$(x-1)^2(5832x^8+972x^7+2646x^6+1477x^5+581x^4+105x^3+51x^2-x+1)\geq0.$$
Done!